# Replace the border with the image

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

The border shows even for the picture since it's done for the entire block. However, I want to hide the border from appearing around the image. What should I do?

```
<div style="border: 1px solid #000">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-24">
            <div style="background-image: url('young.png'); min-height:200px;"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-24">
            <div class="">
                The entire paragraph text is here.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/f28zraee/

Comment: Put the border on the second "row" instead of around the entire block?

Comment: Yes, that's one way to do it. I'm wondering if there's a better way of getting it done though.

Comment: where exactly do you want a border - only around the text block?

Comment: you can can add   "<div style="background-image: url('http://placehold.it/238x159.jpg'); min-height:200px;margin:-1px -1px 0 -1px"></div> "

Answer (score 0):

You have the border around the wrong element, see fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/f28zraee/1/

```
<div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-24">
            <div style="background-image: url('http://placehold.it/238x159.jpg'); min-height:200px;"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-24">
            <div style="border: 1px solid #000; border-top: none;">
                The entire paragraph text is here.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the style attribute from your first line into the `<div>` tag of the second `row`:

```
<div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-24">
            <div style="background-image: url('young.png'); min-height:200px;"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="border: 1px solid #000">
        <div class="col-xs-24">
            <div class="">
                The entire paragraph text is here.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

EDIT: 
Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ye4pn0oz/

What's the downvote for?

Comment: Because you are only half right! Quoted from OP's question "However, I want to hide the border from appearing around the image." now when you make your edited, your answer will be exactly the same as mine... So your answer is no good anymore, sorry.

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith Yours was 2 minutes later - I can't predict the future. I'd say, we wrote it at the same time, but I also could say the same of yours - what kind of logic is that?

Comment: Even if I wrote mine a day later it would not matter. You only answered half the question. What I am saying is that if you modify your answer to completely answer the question then, you will be coping mine. So what's the point?

Comment: Or do you not see the difference between ours and mine?

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith of course I see the difference. What do you want? The OP can decide whatever he wants, but what's the point in you downvoting me because I wrote a similar (but not equal) answer  at the same time?

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith Merry Christmas to you too!